# Only incremental values - PowerBI Calculate between dates

Tags: formula, powerbi, dax

this might look simple.. but dk how to do it

this is the information:

[image: The Slicer select and the information table]

So.. i got the Cumulative Total using this function:

```
CumulativeTotal = CALCULATE(
                      SUM(vnxcritical[Used Space GB]),
                      FILTER(ALL(Datesonly[Date]),
                          Datesonly[Date] <= MAX(Datesonly[Date])))
```

But what i need is to get the differences between the dates, in the first date and the second the difference will be of 210. I need to get another column with that information. know the formula to do that?

ok..

So.. i used this:

```
IncrmentalValueTEST = 
VAR CurrDate = MAX(vnxcritical[Date])
VAR PrevDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(vnxcritical[Date]), vnxcritical[Date] < CurrDate)
RETURN SUM(vnxcritical[Used Space GB]) -
CALCULATE(SUM(vnxcritical[Used Space GB]), vnxcritical[Date] = PrevDate)
```

[image]

and this is the result:

[image]

Ok, so this is is my data table:

[image]

[image]

You can see all the dates that i have for now, this is a capacity report for diferents EMC Storage Arrays, for diferentes Pools. The idea would be to have the knolwdge to review the incremental space used in a determinated portion of time. 
allready tried another idea to get this, but the result was the same.. i used this:

```
Diferencia = 
Var Day = MAX(Datesonly[Month])
Var Month = MAX(Datesonly[Year])
RETURN
SUM('Used Space'[used_mb])
- CALCULATE(
    SUM('Used Space'[used_mb])
    ,FILTER(ALL(Datesonly[Date]),Datesonly[Date] <= Max(Datesonly[Date])))
```

But the return is the same.. "47753152401"

[image]

i'm using graphical filters, and other things to get a minimal view, because there are only 5 weekly reports and the sql database got more than 150.000 rows.

and this is the relation that i made with a only a table full of "dates" in order to invoke the function in a better way, but the result is the same..

[image]

Comment: Why is the difference `210` and not `10,713.26-10,608.61 = 104.65`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson dk it's a problem with the formula or with the decimals, but it's something that will be easy to fix, the thing i need is the incremental value between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
IncrmentalValue = 
    VAR CurrDate = MAX(Datesonly[Date])
    VAR PrevDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(Datesonly[Date]), Datesonly[Date] < CurrDate)
    RETURN SUM(vnxcritical[Used Space GB]) -
           CALCULATE(SUM(vnxcritical[Used Space GB]), Datesonly[Date] = PrevDate)
```

First, calculate the current date and then find the previous date by taking the last date that occurred before it. Then take the difference between the current value and the previous value.

Comment: Okay, so i tried your idea, but dk the result is so estrange, the post is edited.

Comment: Can you show what your data tables look like? Is `vnxcritical` the only one involved in your visual?

Comment: sure, the main topic is edited. dk why the result is allways the same, is like the function is counting all the rows, but it's strange.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Which data table are you trying to use, `vnxcritical` or `Used_Space` or both? If both, how do they differ?

Comment: yes, Used_Space is a new table that i created from vnxcritical, it's the same but i remove some columns. It's the same one or another, only create to get clean columns. But the numbers are the same, the idea is to get the used space column in incremental values